# Problem reading a cookie from within a tracking pixel in IE

Tags: cookies, tracking, pixel, party

I wrote a simple pixel tracking program that works something like this

Step 1) tracker.com sets a cookie
Step 2) mysite.com displays `<img src="tracker.com/tracking.php"`>. That image reads the cookie from Step 1 & does some processing.

Works great in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.  But when tested in IE, the cookie can't be read in Step 2. It's as if the cookie doesn't exist -- but I know it does.

Any idea why IE pretends the cookie doesn't exist?  I've tried messing with P3P headers, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Does your domain have a privacy policy? I forget what it's called, maybe p3p? Some random list of headers that you have to add.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the domain in the src attribute to trusted sites in IE.  My guess is this is security, and you've got a rather arcane security measure you're coming up against.

Comment: Wait -- my fault.  Yeah, I tried that and it works.  Now if only I can figure out how to make it trusted for everyone else..

Answer (score 0):

If the cookie setting domain is 2 letters, I believe there is a bug within IE that prevents IE from doing cookies properly with 2 letter domains. If it isn't 2 letters, then nevermind.

Comment: It's a 5-letter domain.  The domain does have a numerical digit in it, if that means anything.

Answer (score 0):

So, the first answer was more about testing... try using JS to handle this -

From site-reference.com forums..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var track = new Image(); 
track.src="http://www.my-site.com/tracker.php?self=" + this.location;
</script>
```

*NOTE: Capital "I" in image, not lowercase!

Let us know! :D

Fred

Answer (score 0):

It may be that IE is blocking 3rd-party cookies.

Comment: Seems that way.  Funny, I'm only trying to read a 3rd-party (or cross domain) cookie, not write one.  :(

Comment: I think IE blocks it either way, unless you turn off that option.

Answer (score 0):

Its tricky without knowing more specifics of its use, but I'm trying at this late hour to figure out how to clone the cookie for the current domain using REMOTE_ADDR